# how to RedirectToAction to home page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to redirect a page to home page?

```
if (p == -1)
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

this opens webpage like http://abc.com/Index in url
i want just http://abc.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shoul have correct routing with default values in your Global.asax.cs file. 
For example

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
```

and after that

```
if (p == -1)
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Answer (score 8):

Off the top of my head

```
return Redirect("~");
```

Comment: This is actually the only straightforward and working answer I've found searching for 'redirecting to home page'. Off course, it's not actually an answer to the question posted (how to RedirectToAction) but in my case, that was the wrong question, so thank you very much!